# Remove braces and dollar sign from the data using hive regexp_replace

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, regexp-replace

I need to remove dollar-sign and braces from one of the fields in hive.

Sample data:
$210.53
$210.53
($390.53)
($210.53)

The issue is some records have braces and others don't. Below is the syntax I came up with:
select REGEXP_REPLACE(amount, '\(\$|\)','') as amount from table where id=1234;
Output:
$210.53
$210.53
390.53
210.53

This syntax doesn't remove the dollar signs from the records that don't have braces. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: I got it to work:  
select REGEXP_REPLACE(amount, '\\(|\\$|\\)|','') as amount from table where id=1234;

Comment: You might as well use `REGEXP_REPLACE(amount, '[$()]','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work: select REGEXP_REPLACE(amount, '(|\$|)|','') as amount from table where id=1234;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a) dollar-signs and b) parens from a field, you need to write a regular expression that covers these two cases.

Case A:

```
^\$
```

Case B:

```
^\(
\)$
```

Merging these together with the | (alternation) operator you get

```
(^\$|^\(\$|^\(|\)$)
```

Thats:

- $ at beginning
- ($ at beginning
- ( at beginning
- ) at end

If you're CERTAIN your data ALWAYS looks like your examples you could simplify this to:

```
(^\(?\$|\)$)
```

- $ at beginning with an optional leading open-paren
- close-paren at end

(Or as @stribizhev points out):

```
[$()]
```

- characters equal to $, (, )

TMTOWTDI (depending on your data)